# Calling a parameterized constructor from XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml

While using WPF I noticed that when I add a control to a XAML file, the default constructor is called.

Is there a way to call a parameterized constructor?

Answer (score 75):

.NET 4.0 brings a new feature that challenges the answer - but apparently only for UWP applications (not WPF).

[x:Arguments Directive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/xaml-services/x-arguments-directive)

```
<object ...>
    <x:Arguments>
        oneOrMoreObjectElements
    </x:Arguments>
</object>
```

Comment: Nice, I'm glad you brought this up.

Comment: For anyone else who came here looking for exactly this answer, I'll save you some time because you're about to find this post next: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14347181/how-to-fix-xaml2009-language-construct-is-not-allowed-here

Comment: "Basically no current compiler (WPF, SL, WinRT) actually supports it" - Duncan Matheson. Linked by Kevek's comment, should be in the answer.

Comment: What is that `x` namespace defined to?

Comment: Unfortunately this syntax is for XAML 2009 version which means Universal apps, and does not work in WPF sadly.

Answer (score 35):

One of the guiding principles of XAML-friendly objects is that they should be completely usable with a default constructor, i.e., there is no behavior that is only accessible when using a non-default constructor.  To fit with the declarative nature of XAML, object parameters are specified via property setters.  There is also a convention that says that the order in which properties are set in XAML should not be important.

You may, however, have some special considerations that are important to your implementation but at odds with convention:

1. You may have one or more properties which *must* be set before the object can be used.
2. Two or more properties may be mutually exclusive with each other, e.g., it makes no sense to set both the `StreamSource` and `UriSource` of an image.
3. You may want to ensure that a property is *only* set during initialization.
4. One property may depend on another, which can be tricky due to the aforementioned convention of order independence when setting properties.

To make it easier to handle these cases, the `ISupportInitialize` interface is provided.  When an object is read and created from XAML (i.e., parsed), objects implementing `ISupportInitialize` will be handled specially:

1. The default constructor will be called.
2. `BeginInit()` will be called.
3. Properties will be set in the order they appeared in the XAML declaration.
4. `EndInit()` is called.

By tracking calls to `BeginInit()` and `EndInit()`, you can handle whatever rules you need to impose, including the requirement that certain properties be set.  This is how you should handle creation parameters; not by requiring constructor arguments.

Note that `ISupportInitializeNotification` is also provided, which extends the above interface by adding an `IsInitialized` property and `Initialized` event.  I recommend using the extended version.

Answer (score 10):

No. Not from XAML [when using WPF].

Answer (score 10):

Yes, you can do it by the `ObjectDataProvider`. It allows you to call non-default constructor, for example:

```xml
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="myDataSource"
                            ObjectType="{x:Type local:Person}">
            <ObjectDataProvider.ConstructorParameters>
                <system:String>Joe</system:String>
            </ObjectDataProvider.ConstructorParameters>
        </ObjectDataProvider>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <Label Content="{Binding Source={StaticResource myDataSource}, Path=Name}"></Label>
</Grid>
```

assuming that Person is

```cs
public class Person
{
    public Person(string Name)
    {
        this.Name = Name;
    }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Unfortunately, you cannot bind the `ConstructorParameters`. See some workaround [here](http://drwpf.com/blog/2007/09/02/supplying-an-object-reference-in-the-constructorparameters-collection-of-an-objectdataprovider/).

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can do it by using `TypeConverterAttribute` at the class level. If the class you want to use doesn’t have a no-argument constructor then you can decorate your class with `TypeConverter` and you can supply the string representation of your constructor parameters as a `comma-separated` string inside your tag. The XAML parser will then use the type converter to convert that string into the appropriate object. Here’s an example:

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="EmptyWPFApp.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:EmptyWPFApp"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="150" Width="300">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.Resources>
            <local:Person x:Key="MyPerson">
                David,28
            </local:Person>
        </Grid.Resources>
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=WelcomeMessage, Source={StaticResource MyPerson}}" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Source={StaticResource MyPerson}}" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
        </StackPanel>
        
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows;

namespace EmptyWPFApp
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }

    [TypeConverter(typeof(PersonTypeConverter))]
    public class Person
    {
        public Person(string name, int age)
        {
            Name = name;
            Age = age;
        }

        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }

        public string WelcomeMessage => $"Hi I am {Name} and I am {Age} yr old";
    }

    public class PersonTypeConverter : TypeConverter
    {
        public override bool CanConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext context, Type destinationType)
        {


            // We can convert from Person to string
            if (destinationType == typeof(string))
            {
                return true;
            }

            return base.CanConvertTo(context, destinationType);
        }

        public override object ConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext context, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture, object value, Type destinationType)
        {
            if (value is Person person && destinationType == typeof(string))
            {
                return $"{person.Name}, is {person.Age} years old";
            }

            return base.ConvertTo(context, culture, value, destinationType);
        }
        public override object ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture, object value)
        {
            // Convert the string to a Person object
            if (value is string stringValue)
            {
                string[] parts = stringValue.Split(',');
                if (parts.Length == 2)
                {
                    string name = parts[0].Trim();
                    if (int.TryParse(parts[1].Trim(), out int age))
                    {
                        return new Person(name, age);
                    }
                }
            }

            return base.ConvertFrom(context, culture, value);
        }

        public override bool CanConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, Type sourceType)
        {
            // We can convert from string to Person
            if (sourceType == typeof(string))
            {
                return true;
            }

            return base.CanConvertFrom(context, sourceType);
        }
    }
}
```

**Design time Window Display:**
[image]

Answer (score -1):

As explained by Mike, and on the Microsoft website

> [ISupportInitialize](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.isupportinitialize?view=net-8.0) allows controls to optimize multiple property
> assignments. As a result, you can initialize co-dependent properties
> or batch set multiple properties at design time.
>
> Call the BeginInit method to signal the object that initialization is
> starting. Call the EndInit method to signal that initialization is
> complete.

Here is an example of how to implement `ISupportInitialize` in WPF:

My NaturalNumber class has three properties N1,N2,N3 and the order in which the N1, N2, N3 are set are stored in another property `NumbersInOrder`. So the value of this property is different if they are set in different order.

Requirement:

I want `NumbersInOrder` to always evaluate in order of N1,N2,N3 even when they are set in order of N2,N1,N3. So for this I will inherit my class NaturalNumber from `FrameworkElement` and implement the `BeginInit()` & `EndInit()`

[image]

Here is how it appers in XAML designer window now

[image]