# Naming user controls without default constructors in XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml, default-constructor

I have a user control without a parameterless constructor; let's call it `WithoutDefaultConstructor`. I want to insert a `WithoutDefaultConstructor` called `myControl` into the XAML code of another control (which is called `MainWindow`). However, I get this compiler error:

> The type 'WithoutDefaultConstructor'
>   cannot have a Name attribute. Value
>   types and types without a default
>   constructor can be used as items
>   within a ResourceDictionary.

How do I fix this without adding a parameterless constructor to `WithoutDefaultConstructor`?

Here are the contents of `MainWindow.xaml`:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
 xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
 xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
 xmlns:WpfApplication1="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1" Title="MainWindow" 
 Height="350" Width="525">
    <WpfApplication1:WithoutDefaultConstructor Name="myControl">
    </WpfApplication1:WithoutDefaultConstructor>
</Window>
```

Here are the contents of `WithoutDefaultConstructor.xaml.cs`:

```cs
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    public partial class WithoutDefaultConstructor : UserControl
    {
        private int I_really_need_to_initialize_this_int;

        public WithoutDefaultConstructor(int i)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            I_really_need_to_initialize_this_int = i;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not about the `Name` attribute. You just can't create an instance of an object using constructor with parameter from XAML. [There is a way to do it in XAML 2009](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1083159/calling-a-parametrized-constructor-from-xaml/3537280#3537280), but [it's not available in code compiled to BAML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee792007.aspx#xaml_2009_support_in_wpf_and_visual_studio), such as this.

Answer (score 4):

Just don't do it. Instead, expose an `int` property on your user control. If you *really* want to make sure it's explicitly set, expose an `int?` and throw if it's `null`.