# Modifying a Usercontrol that accepted parameters to be inside a DataTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I had a UserControl that accepted several parameters in its constructor. Because I'm now binding to a collection of ViewModel's it seems the best way to load a UserControl based on a ViewModel is with a DataTemplate.

eg.

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="ContentTemplate" DataType="{x:Type vm:WhiteboardVM}">
   <local:WhiteboardUC  />
</DataTemplate>
```

However I still need the Usercontrol to have the parameters when it initialises. How can I achieve this? Or what options do I have?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have to pass the parameters in the constructor? Why can't they just be properties on the UserControl?

Comment: The Usercontrol has a gridview with columns that have an order based on one of the parameters. There's also a lot of controls that's visibility is determined by the type of parameter. Though I could have a converter for visibility I can't think of a way to order the columns.

Comment: You [can use](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1083159/calling-a-parametrized-constructor-from-xaml) parametrized constructor in .NET 4.0, but this is really ugly solution IMHO. Consider using dependency properties on your control

Comment: It doesn't work for me anyway (I get the error "Tags of type 'DefTag' are not supported in template sections"). If you know of a good example of creating an enum and bool dependency properties that achieve the same aim as passing a parameter I'd love to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameterized construction of GUI elements is possible using `ObjectDataProvider` but **dynamic parameter values are not allowed** e.g. using the data template below in an `ItemsControl.ItemTemplate` is not possible if you expect to pass on items specific parameter value!  ...

**XAML:**

```
<Window x:Class="LDAPAutocomplete.Window1"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:LDAPAutocomplete"
        xmlns:System="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
        Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="MyContentTemplate">
            <DataTemplate.Resources>
                <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="MyUserControlProvider"
                                    ObjectType="{x:Type local:MyButton}">
                    <ObjectDataProvider.ConstructorParameters>
                        <System:String>Test Me</System:String>
                    </ObjectDataProvider.ConstructorParameters>
                </ObjectDataProvider>
            </DataTemplate.Resources>
            <ContentPresenter
                   Content="{Binding
                        Source={StaticResource MyUserControlProvider}}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>
    <StackPanel>
        <local:LDAPAutocompleteTextBox/>
        <ContentControl
             ContentTemplate="{StaticResource MyContentTemplate}"
                   Content="123"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

**Code Behind:**

```
public class MyButton : Button
{
    public MyButton(string content)
    {
        this.Content = content;
    }
}
```