# Why do I have to declare a custom ValueConverter as a StaticResource and bind to the resource, instead of binding to its type?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Given this class:

```
namespace My.App.Converters
{
  [ValueConversion(typeof(bool?), typeof(Visibility))]
  public class NullableBooleanToVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
  {
    ...
  }
}
```

Why do I have to do the following:

```
<UserControl ...
             xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:My.App.Converters">
  <UserControl.Resources>
    <converters:NullableBooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="visibilityConverter" />
  </UserControl.Resources>
  ...
  <Button MinWidth="120" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
          Visibility="{Binding BackButtonVisible, Converter={StaticResource visibilityConverter}}" />
  ...
</UserControl>
```

instead of being able to do something like the following:

```
<UserControl ...
             xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:My.App.Converters">
  ...
  <Button MinWidth="120" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
          Visibility="{Binding BackButtonVisible, ConverterType={x:Type converters:NullableBooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" />
  ...
</UserControl>
```

given that I only ever want to use this particular converter in a single place in my app, i.e. this particular `UserControl`?

Is the answer as simple as "Microsoft didn't feel like adding a `ConverterType` and you can do it yourself with markup extensions if you really want", or is there a reason of good programming style for doing it this way? ("Reusability" doesn't count for this example.)

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you are not getting an instance of your converter. To solve the same just add a static instance of your converter to your NullableBooleanToVisibilityConverter class, like this

```
namespace My.App.Converters
{
  [ValueConversion(typeof(bool?), typeof(Visibility))]
  public class NullableBooleanToVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
  {
    public static NullableBooleanToVisibilityConverter Instance = new NullableBooleanToVisibilityConverter();

   /* Convert and ConvertBack methods */
  }
}
```

**EDIT**

I forgot to mention that in the binding also you have to access the static Instance

```
<Button MinWidth="120" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
          Visibility="{Binding BackButtonVisible, Converter={x:Static:NullableBooleanToVisibilityConverter.Instance}}" />
```

Comment: this won't help the OP, as this static property named "Instance" is not automatically used. You had to assign the "Instance" to the binding, e.g. by using the {x:Static}-extension. But would this be any benefit over using a StaticResource? (except for the support of a non-default constructor)

Comment: @eFloh Yes, I forgot to mention that you we need to use this Instance in binding. Please see my updated code. Also adding to your question - The benefit of this Instance is that we don't have to define this static resource in every page.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot provide just the type because your converter may not have a `default parameterless constructor`. Therefore, a dynamic instance of the converter cannot be magicked out of thin air with just the type.

The idiom you *want* to use introduces a problem of creating a new convert every time the binding updates - this is bad practice from a performance point of view. You can prevent that by caching the converter but now there are even more issues;

- when should the cache be refreshed (generate a new converter)?
- when should the cache be disposed?
- how do i change parameters on my converter and ensure that they won't be lost later when the cache refreshes?

Comment: why do you assume there is no public ctor()?

Comment: @eFloh "**may not** have a default parameterless constructor". There are no guarantees that activator will succeed to create the instance. This makes the pattern significantly less useful than explicit resource creation and the associated benefits.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I overread the 'may'. and how would a static resource declaration use a non-default ctor? I assume you could declare the resource in code, but normally that wouldn't be my favorite...

Comment: @eFloh http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1083159/calling-a-parametrized-constructor-from-xaml In .net 3.5, you would have to set properties separately.

Answer (score 0):

```
ConverterType={x:Type converters:NullableBooleanToVisibilityConverter}
```

Do this has the instance of your Converter? Though your thought was good but by giving the Type Binding will not take the instance of that converter..

Answer (score 0):

By using an instance of the converter, you may use a converter with properties set to specific values, consider this (theoretical) example:

```
<UserControl ...
             xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:My.App.Converters">
  <UserControl.Resources>
    <converters:NullableBooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="visibilityConverter"
                                                     IsInverted="True" />
  </UserControl.Resources>
  ...
  <Button MinWidth="120" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
          Visibility="{Binding BackButtonVisible, Converter={StaticResource visibilityConverter}}" />
  ...
</UserControl>
```

if you absolutely don't want to use a resource, you may declare the instance inline:

```
<UserControl ...
             xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:My.App.Converters">
  ...
  <Button MinWidth="120" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
          Visibility="{Binding BackButtonVisible, Converter={StaticResource visibilityConverter}}" />
    <Button.Visiblity>
      <Binding Path="BackButtonVisible">
        <Binding.Converter>
          <converters:NullableBooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="visibilityConverter" />
        </Binding.Converter>
      </Binding>
    </Button>
  ...
</UserControl>
```