# Passing information through viewmodels

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

When opening a client file, i need the clientId that was selected to indicate which record should be queryed. I'm trying to expose the ViewModel as a static resource on the page so that it can be easily accessible by the binding.

Reason for Binding to a static resource can be found through this link.
http://www.telerik.com/help/silverlight/gridview-troubleshooting-blank-cells.html

```
// Open an individual record when double-clicked.
public void Open()
{
    if (SelectedItem != null)
    {
        var vm = new LoanViewModel(Events);
        vm.ById(SelectedItem.Id);
        Events.PublishOnUIThread(new ShowTabEvent(vm));
    }
    this.OnPropertyChanged("Items");
}
```

LoanViewModel.cs

```
public LoanViewModel()
{ .... Query needs LoanId}

public void ById(int id)
{}
```

More info is from this linked Question [Having my Viewmodel appear in namespace dropdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27115192/having-my-viewmodel-appear-in-namespace-dropdown/27133076#27133076)

Comment: This is an excellent example of a good follow-up question. Thank you for not making the old one a chameleon question. One suggestion (even though its pretty obvious what you want): include your current XAML and what you *want* it to look like (even if you don't know the syntax yet).

Comment: On a side note; I'm having trouble determining what exactly is wrong with what you have. I understand *basically* what you want to do; but not where you are having trouble.

Comment: Thank you @BradleyDotNET So when my tab is open through LoanViewModel() I get many null references because the loanID has not been established. Which is why I need the loanID.

Comment: Why can't you pass it on the constructor?

Comment: The sequence of operation at the moment is ById then LoanViewModel. Is there a way to set a "Super int Variable" such that when LoanViewModel() it can call it? I tried to simply set public int LoanId {get; set;} and within ById it sets the value, but that didn't quite work. LoanId would still be empty when LoanViewModel() is triggered. I can't pass it on the constructor because I dont have the loanID on the xaml side of the application.

Comment: But in the code above, you are constructing the VM *outside* of the XAML (and you could probably make even that work). You can always have a global object that maintains state between forms; its not the most elegant solution, but it works (and with enough effort, *can* be elegant).

Answer (score 0):

First, you shouldn't do a query operation within the ViewModels constructor. You shouldn't do any "expensive" operation within the constructor of a class.

Second, ViewModels shouldn't be aware of other ViewModels. So you shouldn't instantiate a ViewModel within another ViewModel.

I would suggest a different approach. Instead of trying to pass an ID to the ViewModel directly, do it via an event aggregator. Event Aggregator is basically a messaging system to send messages in a decoupled way between ViewModels.

One ViewModel register to a certain event, the other ViewModel sends it's event without know if there is any subscriber to this event or who this subscriber may be. For example the PRISM `IEventAggregator`.

You obtain an instance of the EventAgregator of your choice within your ViewModel (either by Dependency Injection or via Service Locator) and register your event in the constructor

```
public class LoanViewModel 
{
    public LoanViewModel()
    {
        IEventAggregator events = ... ; // get via ServiceLocator or via Constructor for DI
        events.GetEvent<CustomerLoadedEvent>().Subscribe(OnCustomerLoaded);
    }

    private void OnCustomerLoaded(Customer customer) 
    {
        int customerId = customer.ID;

        // do your query now
    }
}

public class OtherViewModel 
{
    IEventAggregator events;

    public LoanViewModel()
    {
        this.events; = ... ; // get via ServiceLocator or via Constructor for DI
    }

    // Should be ICommand for WPF binding...assuming SelectedItem is from type Customer
    public void Open() 
    {
        if (SelectedItem != null)
        {
            events.GetEvent<CustomerLoadedEvent>().Publish(SelectedItem);
        }
        this.OnPropertyChanged("Items");
    }
}
```

This way your ViewModels are completely decoupled from each other.

Of course PRISM/CompositeFramework may be a bit overkill for what you need. You can use other, simpler Event Aggregators or make your own one. Api may be different, the idea is the same

Comment: I do like your approach, the only issue is that it's one Viewmodel. Not two seperate. Not sure if it'll have the same effect/.