# Is it not possible to deserialize to 'this' from default constructor?

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, xml-serialization

**The Situation:**

I have a ViewModel bound to a Settings View, where the user is supposed to enter a lot of personalized settings and should be able to save them as presets and load them. For this the ViewModel holds Collections of preset data models which themselves hold different properties, class objects and so on. 
The plan is to achieve saving all the presets by xml serialization and deserialization of the whole ViewModels.

**The Code / The Problem**

From the Constructor of the ViewModel I call the following method:

```
private void InitializePresetsFromFile()
{
    if (!File.Exists(Info.GetDefaultColorPalettePresetsXml()))
    {
        SetupNewEmpty();
        SerializePresets(Info.GetDefaultColorPalettePresetsXml());
    }
    else
    {
        DeserializePresets(Info.GetDefaultColorPalettePresetsXml());
    }
}
```

So the Method checks if the file holding the preset exists - if it doesn't it should setup an empty preset and save it to a newly created file, otherwise it should load the preset from the existing file.

The serialization process works fine, however since I serialize to `this` there is a problem with deserializiation:

```
private void DeserializePresets(string path)
{
    XmlSerializer deserializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(LinearAxisColorPresetsViewModel));
    TextReader reader = new StreamReader(path);
    object obj = deserializer.Deserialize(reader);
    LinearAxisColorPresetsViewModel XmlData = (LinearAxisColorPresetsViewModel)obj;
    reader.Close();
    VolumePresetList = XmlData.VolumePresetList;
    WaveShapePresetList = XmlData.WaveShapePresetList;
    VolumePresetSelectedIndex = XmlData.VolumePresetSelectedIndex;
    WaveShapePresetSelectedIndex = XmlData.WaveShapePresetSelectedIndex;
}
```

The problem here is, that since I'm calling the method `InitializePresetsFromFile()` directly from the constructor, the deserializer calls himself in an never ending loop resulting in an stackoverflow error.

So, the most simple solution should be to use another constructor with a parameter, where I call `InitializePresetsFromFile()`, right? The problem here is that the ViewModel class is directly instantiated within the xaml of the corresponding View:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <vm:LinearAxisColorPresetsViewModel x:Key="vm" />
    </ResourceDictionary>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

[This posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1083159/calling-a-parameterized-constructor-from-xaml) second answer states that convention is, that constructors called from XAML should be parameterless and I want to stick to that.

**The question:**

The question is simply how to go about this problem according to best practice. Since this is my first attempt on serialization and deserialization I fear, that I'm a bit on the wrong path here. My feeling is that only data model classes should be serialized. My ViewModel holds two ObservableCollection of such classes, however I want to serialize the complete collections as well as other properties within the ViewModel such as the selected index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have indeed reached a point where you have to decide how to continue. What you are doing now is not going to work. Both the XML serializer and XAML uses the default constructor in this case. You can't make it serve two purposes here.

My advice would be to create a class that mirrors the properties from your view model which you use to deserialize the XML file. This class only needs the properties, nothing more.

If the view model class is actually a static, you could use [a locator class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991965.aspx) to bind it to.

Comment: Hmm, I feared this answer...I'll have a look into your suggested use of a locator class and see if I can implement it in my case. Thanks!

Comment: Would be using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171970/how-can-i-find-the-method-that-called-the-current-method) approach to find out who is calling the constructor and only calling `InitializePresetsFromFile();` good practice? I still have to test it, but I guess it should work..

Comment: I would not recommend that. Make it transparent for the next colleague who sees that code what it does and don't do such obscure things...

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you shouldn't call the `InitializePresetsFromFile` method in a class' constructor. The constructor must be as fast as possible and should not cause side effects. Reading a file in constructor is a bad practice: you can't create an instance of your class without accessing the file system. This means your code is not testable, it is error-prone (e.g. did you think about sudden `UnauthorizedAccessException`s?), and it is slow.

Instead, create a public method that deserializes the data from the file. This will break your endless recursion.

How to call that method?

- Do you really need your `LinearAxisColorPresetsViewModel` instance in the resource dictionary? If not, just assign the deserialized instance to the `DataContext` property of your view.
- If you do need that, create in your view-model an `ICommand` e.g. `InitializeCommand` that uses the above mentioned method to initialize the internal state from a file; execute that command on app startup/view show-up etc. You could use e.g. `InvokeCommandAction` for the `Loaded` event for that.

Comment: These are valid points. I will probably try to put all data needed for serialization in its own class as suggested by Patrick Hofman and start the deserialization process from the `loaded` event as you have suggested.